# why is the session name appended to the role name when trying to connect to AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

I am trying to create a job with Amazon Glue, using boto3. I'm using STS to connect to the AWS account, as per the following code:

```
session_name = 'glue_job_creation'
client = boto3.client("sts",region_name="eu-west-1",endpoint_url="https://sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")
response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=arn , RoleSessionName=session_name)
temp_credentials = response["Credentials"]

glue = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name='eu-west-1',
                endpoint_url='https://glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
                aws_access_key_id=temp_credentials["AccessKeyId"],
                aws_secret_access_key=temp_credentials["SecretAccessKey"],
                aws_session_token=temp_credentials["SessionToken"])

def list_glue_jobs():
    response = glue.list_jobs()
    print(response)

def create_glue_job():
    print('creating new glue job...')
    print(response)
    myJob = glue.create_job(Name='sample', Role=JobRole,
                            Command={'Name': 'glueetl',
                                    'ScriptLocation': script_location})

    myNewJobRun = glue.start_job_run(JobName=myJob['Name'])
    return myNewJobRun
```

The `list_job` function works alright, but the `create_job` doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/assumed-role-name/session-name is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/assumed-role because no identity-based policy allows the iam:PassRole action
```

I do not understand why the `session-name` is appended to the User ARN in this case. Also, is the solution to this simply to create an IAM role with the session name appended to the role name like `assumed-role/role-name`, or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session name is just an arbitrary string to identify when someone/something is using an IAM role. Since IAM roles have no credentials like IAM users, the only way to use IAM roles is to *assume* them. For example EC2 machines assume the IAM role attached to them and use their instance ID as the session name so in the CloudTrail logs you can see which instance is using that IAM role, even if multiple instances are assuming the same IAM role.

So when you see something like this:
`arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/assumed-role-name/session-name`
it just means:

> I am `session-name` and I am using IAM role `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/assumed-role-name`

Note that the actual IAM role has `aws:iam` in the ARN and the assumed roles have `aws:sts` in the ARN. The assumed role ARN with the session name is a temporary session and not an existing IAM resource/document that you can create/update. More details about assuming IAM roles can be found in the [STS AssumeRole API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html).

So in your example, the `session-name` who is using the IAM role `assumed-role-name` wants to call `iam:PassRole` with `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/assumed-role`.

The solution is to extend your `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/assumed-role-name` role with this policy statement:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/assumed-role",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "iam:PassedToService": [
                "glue.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow the user of the `assumed-role-name` IAM role to pass the `assumed-role` IAM role to the created Glue jobs, so the new Glue jobs can run as `assumed-role` and use the permissions specified in that IAM role.

If interested, you can read more on `iam:PassRole` in the ["Granting permissions to pass a role to a service" AWS IAM doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html).
And the AWS Glue documentation ["Attach a policy to IAM users that access AWS Glue"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/attach-policy-iam-user.html) has more info about why this is needed for AWS Glue (note the Important section bout the PassRole requirement).

Comment: Thank you very much! This works now, and I now have a better understanding of IAM!